# Confused about timers and microtasks in Nodejs event loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, timer, event-loop

I'm confused about the output of the code below. (Taken from IBM developer Nodejs course).

```
'use strict'

const logger = require('../common/logger');

const { MAINLINE, START, END } = require('../common/constants');

(function mainline() {
    logger.info(START, MAINLINE);
    
    process.nextTick(() => {
        logger.info('mainline:process.nextTick() says: hello!', 'MICROTASK')
    });

    let iteration = 0;
    let intervalTimeout = setInterval(() => {
        if (iteration < 3) {
            setTimeout((iteration) => {
                logger.info('setInterval(' + iteration + '):setTimeout() says: Timer expired!', 'TIMERS');
                process.nextTick((iteration) => {
                    logger.info('setInterval():setTimeout(' + iteration + '):process.nextTick() says: Delimit TIMERS phase!', 'MICROTASK');
                }, iteration);
            }, 0, iteration);
        } else {
            logger.info('setInterval(' + iteration + ') says: Goodbye!', 'TIMERS');
            clearInterval(intervalTimeout);
        }
        iteration++;
    });

    logger.info(END, MAINLINE)
})();
```

The output is as follows:

```
1593574413204:INFO: MAINLINE: START
1593574413206:INFO: MAINLINE: END
1593574413207:INFO: MICROTASK: mainline:process.nextTick() says: hello!
1593574413210:INFO: TIMERS: setInterval(0):setTimeout() says: Timer expired!
1593574413210:INFO: MICROTASK: setInterval():setTimeout(0):process.nextTick() says: Delimit TIMERS phase!
1593574413211:INFO: TIMERS: setInterval(1):setTimeout() says: Timer expired!
1593574413211:INFO: MICROTASK: setInterval():setTimeout(1):process.nextTick() says: Delimit TIMERS phase!
1593574413213:INFO: TIMERS: setInterval(2):setTimeout() says: Timer expired!
1593574413213:INFO: TIMERS: setInterval(3) says: Goodbye!
1593574413213:INFO: MICROTASK: setInterval():setTimeout(2):process.nextTick() says: Delimit TIMERS phase!
```

Why does the logger log "Goodbye" before the final timer microtask?

Comment: IMO, you would never rely on the detailed inner workings of the event loop to make sure this micro-ordering of tasks occurred to your wishes.  If you want B to occur after A, you would just code it that way to sequence it rather than relying on the inner details of how the event loop works.  Hopefully someone will come along and attempt to explain why it does what it does, but IMO it should be largely irrelevant to how you actually code two operations that demand a particular ordering and this is mostly an academic excercise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe if you rewrite this code using a recursive setTimeout instead of setInterval that would make it clearer what happens.

That would give something like

```js
(function mainline() {

  let iteration = 0;
  function intervalJob() {
    if (iteration < 3) {
      setTimeout(timeoutJob, 0, interation);
      // reproduce what setInterval does using recursive setTimeout
      setTimeout(intervalJob, 0);
    }
    else {
      logger.info('setInterval(' + iteration + ') says: Goodbye!', 'TIMERS');
    }
    iteration++;
  }
  function timeoutJob(iteration) {
    logger.info('setInterval(' + iteration + '):setTimeout() says: Timer expired!', 'TIMERS');
    process.nextTick(microtaskJobFromTimeout, iteration);
  }
  function microtaskJobFromTimeout(iteration) {
    logger.info('setInterval():setTimeout(' + iteration + '):process.nextTick() says: Delimit TIMERS phase!', 'MICROTASK');
  }

  logger.info("START", "MAINLINE");
  
  process.nextTick(() => {
    console.log('mainline:process.nextTick() says: hello!', 'MICROTASK')
  });
  
  setTimeout(intervalJob,0);
  
  logger.info("END", "MAINLINE")

})();
```

Basically, before `iteration` reaches `3`, each `intervalJob` call will schedule **two** new jobs to get executed at the next event loop iteration: `timeoutJob`, which itself will internally schedule a microtask, and the recursive `intervalJob`.

Because node's event loop does first executes all timeouts jobs, then only all microtasks, the last `intervalJob` will actually be in the pool of timeouts during the same event loop iteration than the last `timeoutJob`.

So `timeoutJob` is normally executed before, since it was scheduled first, then `intervalJob` because it was in the pool of timers too, and finally the microtask, before the loop reiterates.

You can verify this by logging unconditionally from the *setInterval* callback, the output would be:

> MAINLINE: START
> MAINLINE: END
> MICROTASK: mainline:process.nextTick() says: hello!
> INTERVALJOB: unconditional intervalJob logging
> TIMERS: setInterval(0):setTimeout() says: Timer expired!
> INTERVALJOB: unconditional intervalJob logging
> MICROTASK: setInterval():setTimeout(0):process.nextTick() says: Delimit TIMERS phase!
> TIMERS: setInterval(1):setTimeout() says: Timer expired!
> INTERVALJOB: unconditional intervalJob logging
> MICROTASK: setInterval():setTimeout(1):process.nextTick() says: Delimit TIMERS phase!
> TIMERS: setInterval(2):setTimeout() says: Timer expired!
> TIMERS: setInterval(3) says: Goodbye!
> INTERVALJOB: unconditional intervalJob logging
> MICROTASK: setInterval():setTimeout(2):process.nextTick() says: Delimit TIMERS phase!

*Note that this is node specific behavior, in browsers each task will have its own microtasks checkpoint and two timers scheduled to fire at the same time will actually get executed on two different event loop iterations*.